# lime-object.lua: 495 bad argument #1 'newLine' (number expected, got string)

Tags: sdk, coronasdk, lime

I'm stuck with the Lime tutorial "08 – Complex Physics Objects" 
http://lime.outlawgametools.com/tutorials/08-complex-physics-objects/

everything works fine until i set the  “pointA”, “pointB”, “pointC” than i get the following error in corona:

```
lime-object.lua: 495 bad argument #1 'newLine' (number expected, got string)
```

full error screenshot: 
http://i48.fastpic.ru/big/2013/0620/f4/d72939cb162476a7361889f797e8f2f4.png

Comment: I have the same issue as well, the author has a "email me" on his page that goes to a 404 :/ bummer.

Answer (score -1):

I did find this here:

http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/34576-hextorgb-error/

If you follow the rest of the thread you will see the user has had the same issue and other uers have as well and had to change up their sprite stuff separately it looks like?
 oh well might be worth giving it a look.

Comment: I think my error is not related. file that responsible for `points` is lime-objectLayer.lua and it was changed 7 days ago, I think the author did a mistake while fixing something else https://github.com/OutlawGameTools/Lime2DTileEngine/tree/master/lime i emailed him, hope he'll fix it soon

Comment: ahh okay.  There was another thread in the above one though I thought might of been the error (second post) but just was throwing it out there this has slowed me down as well and I am enjoying it so far.

Comment: definitely keep me posted on this here if he emails back with an answer.